# An error thrown by a React component, being caught in an unrelated promise's catch block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

Here's what I bumped into. Somewhere in a React component's render function, I have this:

```
{first_name} {last_name}
```

I replaced it with this:

```
{first_name.toUpperCase()} {last_name.toUpperCase()}
```

And my application could no longer log in. I'm using Axios to talk to the backend. Axios is promise-based. And after I made the change above. It apparently started executing both the `then` and the `catch` block of my `login` API call. As I print the response in the `catch` block.

```
function login(data, success, error) {
  axios.post('/login',
    JSON.stringify(data),
    {
      baseURL: config.apiUrl,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    })
  .then((response) => success(response.data))
  .catch((response) => {
    console.log(response)
    error(response.status)})
}
```

I get the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
```

There is absolutely no relationship between the component above (it's a dumb component simply displaying stuff from props on the page) and the API calling code.

This is not the first time I bump into this issue in my app. Has anyone ever bumped into anything like this before? I understand that my variables in the component are undefined, and that's why the error comes up. My question is how does it make it into the catch block of the promise somewhere on the other end of the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out that in JavaScript, any `catch` block will catch any error that is being thrown anywhere in the code. And that is by design.

Here's the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw):

> The `throw` statement throws a user-defined exception. Execution of
>   the current function will stop (the statements after throw won't be
>   executed), and control will be passed to the first `catch` block in
>   the call stack. If no `catch` block exists among caller functions, the
>   program will terminate.

One workaround is to use a handler on all the promises that you introduce, that would `console.log` anything that it didn't expect, such as this:

```
export function apiErrorHandler(handler) {
  return (error) => {
    if (error.stack) {
      throw error
    }
    if (error.status && error.data) {
      handler(error)
    } else {
      console.error('Unknown type of error thrown during service request or its handler:', error)
    }
  }
}
```

And than plug it into the axios service:

```
export function serviceGetContacts(success, error) {
  axios.get(`/contacts`, cfg())
    .then((response) => success(response.data))
    .catch(apiErrorHandler(error))
}
```

Comment: Given that this is by design, could you provide insight as to why this is the desired behavior?

Comment: This is JavaScript. By design != desired behavior. ))

Comment: Why is the Axios call part of the call stack of the rendering of that component though? I'm running into the same problem as errbody else [here](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/66)

Comment: @LeoLei It's not part of the call stack. See the spec link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your change will throw a TypeError if either first or last name is not yet defined.  Which is pretty likley before the login process has completed.

Try using this instead:

```
{first_name && first_name.toUpperCase()} {last_name && last_name.toUpperCase()}
```

Comment: I added a clarification to the question, please see the last paragraph.